# Android TV How To Prevent Other Applications In The Background From Using Media Buttons

Tags: android, onkeydown, television, amazon-fire-os

On my Android TV if I launch Pandora in the background and let music play, then launch my app.
From my application if I press pause or next it receives these on my applicaiotn but also affects Pandora.

How can I prevent background applications from receiving these inputs.
I tried obtaining audio focus which effectively stops the music but if button input is made again music will resume.

Any ideas?

Here is my code capturing remote inputs.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) == InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
                    moveToNextImage(true);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:
                    moveToPreviousImage(true);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                    playPauseController();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! To prevent other applications from receiving remote inputs while my app is active, add the handled boolean.
Other option was gaining audio focus, but since I was not using audio it was not needed.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if ((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) == InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
                    moveToNextImage(true);
                    handled = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:
                    moveToPreviousImage(true);
                    handled = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                    playPauseController();
                    handled = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return handled || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```